# Flutter iOS could not build the precompiled application for the device

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm trying to run my Flutter code on a real-device, but I am encountering a code signing issue. See logs.

In Xcode, the project seems to have been using using the right team identifier. I use my machine to work on various Flutter & iOS projects.

**Logs**

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Building a deployable iOS app requires a selected Development Team with a 
Provisioning Profile. Please ensure that a Development Team is selected by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected under Signing & Capabilities > Team. 
     You may need to:
         - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
         - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
         - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
         - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again

For more information, please visit:
  https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices

Or run on an iOS simulator without code signing
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Error launching application on Joshua’s iPhone 13.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you've encountered this issue, it's likely that the project you just opened is using the old certs.

To make sure you're using the correct certs for your Flutter project, in the command line clear the config:

```
flutter config --clear-ios-signing-cert
```

*This is going to force your Flutter app to use the new certificates.*

Next, restart the terminal.

Last, make sure the Xcode project is using the provisioning profile/s.

1. From the Projects / left side panel of Xcode, click `Runner`
2. Under `TARGETS`, click `Runner`
3. Next, click `Signing & Capabilities`
4. Last, choose the correct provisioning profile/s